# Long executing time return 500

Tags: php, laravel, iis-6

I am trying to run a function in IIS - Laravel which takes about 3mins.

I just don't know why Laravel return 500.

Although I tried add the construct below

```
public function __construct()
{
    set_time_limit(2000);
}
```

When I run this function still get 500 without any error.

```
public function import(Request $request) 
{
    try {
        sleep(300);
        return '123';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how fix this error?

Comment: its not a good idea make job and push the job to queue and process it

Comment: @Manojkiran.A Actually I am not push the job to queue. It just my function takes about 3mins to run it...I found out the Angular gets 500 error just because my Laravel backend can't run the job more than 30seonds~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason...
It's the setting in IIS7.5 - activity timeout